# MySQL SET rank over First Column and Second Column

Tags: mysql, set, rank, partition

I'm trying to make a query setting rank column by First and Second column. Like Rank over Partition which doesn't exist MySQL

For example,

From

```
+----+-------+--------+------+
| id | First | Second | Rank |
+----+-------+--------+------+
|  1 | a     |     10 |      |
|  2 | a     |      9 |      |
|  3 | b     |     10 |      |
|  4 | b     |      7 |      |
|  5 | a     |      1 |      |
|  6 | b     |      1 |      |
+----+-------+--------+------+
```

To

```
+----+-------+--------+------+
| id | First | Second | Rank |
+----+-------+--------+------+
|  1 | a     |     10 |    3 |
|  2 | a     |      9 |    2 |
|  3 | b     |     10 |    3 |
|  4 | b     |      7 |    2 |
|  5 | a     |      1 |    1 |
|  6 | b     |      1 |    1 |
+----+-------+--------+------+
```

The Rank doesn't continue. It starts from 1 again when it reaches the last value of 'a' of 'First' column.

And it's gotta be SET not SELECT.
I wouldn't mind using SELECT but my point is I'm not trying to retrieve data from Database but setting values.

Cheers in advance mates.

Comment: But why store derived data?

Comment: Can't afford to order by every time requested

Comment: I don't understand. What's the cost?

Comment: My Django Server can't order the table everytime requested. since it can be a thousand times per minutes. So my team decided to store the rank data on the table column. Since "select rank where id= x" will be much faster than ordering every rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a solution which I was looking for.
I'm not sure if these queries are completely safe but so far no harms.

```
SET @rank = 0, @First = ''
UPDATE 'Table' SET 
rank = IF(@First = First, @rank:= @rank +1, @rank := 1 AND @First := First)
ORDER BY First ASC, Second;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,first CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,second INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'a',10),
(2,'a',9),
(3,'b',10),
(4,'b',7),
(5,'a',1),
(6,'b',1);

SELECT id
     , first
     , second
     , rank 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.* 
            , CASE WHEN @prev = first THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
            , @prev:=first 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY first
            , second
            , id
     ) a
 ORDER 
    BY id;
+----+-------+--------+------+
| id | first | second | rank |
+----+-------+--------+------+
|  1 | a     |     10 |    3 |
|  2 | a     |      9 |    2 |
|  3 | b     |     10 |    3 |
|  4 | b     |      7 |    2 |
|  5 | a     |      1 |    1 |
|  6 | b     |      1 |    1 |
+----+-------+--------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Any other solution rather than dropping the table??

Comment: Oh man, I give up. Where's the emoji for banging a head against a wall?

Comment: Thanks heaps for your try. I'm just trying to satisfy my boss so I can negotiate salary on the better position.

Comment: Do I get a cut?

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery.  For `rank()` you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) + 1
        from t t2
        where t2.first = t.first and t2.second < t.second
       ) as rank
from t;
```

Ranks are tricky to handle with variables (`dense_rank()` and `row_number()` are simpler).

EDIT:

This is easy to turn into an `update`:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
               (select count(*) + 1
                from t t2
                where t2.first = t.first and t2.second < t.second
               ) as new_rank
        from t
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set t.rank = tt.new_rank;
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea but as I mentioned it's gotta be update instead of select